# Oracle: Siebel Licenses

Tags: oracle, siebel

Can anyone comment on below query regarding Siebel Licenses.

1. What is the difference b/w "Siebel CRM Base - Application User Perpetual" and "Siebel Communications, Media and Energy CRM Base Option - Application User Perpetual".
2. Do i need both or the later will have all the functionality of former.
3. What are these two modules for:
   "Siebel CME Quote and Order Capture - Application User Perpetual"
   "Siebel Configurator Runtime - Application User Perpetual"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Programming question.

Comment: Oracle TechNet forums have a community devoted to Seibel. You're way more likely to get some form of answer there than you are on a general programming site. [Check it out here](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications/siebel/install_upgrade_manage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all fairness to the comments, I think that the right answer should come from your software vendor. In this case Oracle. They will be happy to tell you if CME base is dependent on CRM Base.

As for the other question: Quote and Order capture is just that: the functionality regarding the creation of Quotes and Orders in Siebel. This includes the screens, views and underlying functionality. In a quote and order you can use the Simple products with a few simple attributes. However, if you desire complex logic and ruling regarding your product model, x excludes Y, F includes U etc. The Siebel Configurator module is needed.

Comment: Thanks. That helps.